# How to update a JSON field that wasn't created in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I have a Model : **Place**, where when I create the record in the Mongodb database I set some field such as :
*place_name*, *description*, *capacity* and in the JSON *place_address* all the attributes instead of *latitude* and *longitude*.

In the **PlaceController.js**, I have an update method where I want to update in the JSON *place_address* the *latitude* and *longitude* field which weren't set.

The only way to do that is to create a new JSON *place_address* where I get all the previous parameters and I set the *latitude* and *longitude*.

Is there an easier way to do that like : (but the following code doesn't work)

In **PlaceController.js**

```
Place.update(id, {
            place_address.latitude : req.param('latitude'),
            place_address.longitude : req.param('longitude')
})
```

For a better understanding here is the Model **Place.js** :

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        place_name : {
            type : 'string',
            required : true,    
        },
        description : {
            type : 'string',
            required : true,
        },
        capacity : {
            type : 'string',
            required : true,
        },
        place_address : {
            type : 'json',
            required : true,
        },
        office_hours: {
            type : 'array'
        },
        conditions: {
            type : 'json'
        },
        functions: {
            type : 'array'
        },
        owners: {
            type : 'array'
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the Controller **PlaceController.js** :

```
update: function (req,res) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        var placeJSON = {street_number: req.param('street_number'), street_name: req.param('street_name'), additional_info: req.param('additional_info'), postcode: req.param('postcode'), town: req.param('town'), country: req.param('country')};

        if (!id) {
            console.log("No id specified.");
            return res.send("No id specified.",500);
        }

        Place.update(id, {
            place_name : req.param('place_name'),
            description : req.param('description'),
            capacity : req.param('capacity'),
            place_address : placeJSON
        }).exec(function (err, updatedPlace) {
            if (err) {
                res.redirect('/place/edit');
            }
            if(!updatedPlace) {
                res.redirect('/place/edit');
            }
            //res.redirect('/place');
            res.redirect('/place/show/'+id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: it is recommended to use the `populate` function for inner json objects 

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate

Comment: as @AkramSaouri wrote already - create additional model and use assosiation and then populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`populate` sails function helps you express the association between collections, in your cases the **Place** and **Coordinate** can be made like this:

```
// create new place and coordinates 
Place.create(placeParams).then((place) => {
        Coordinate.create(coordianteParams).then((coordinate) => {
            Place.findOne(lesson.id).populate('coordinates').then((place) => {
                    res.json(place);
                })
            })

// get place and coordinates 
Place.find({}}.popupale('coordinates').then((places) => {
res.json(places)
});
```

this approach enables to update *separately* the coordinates and re-attach them to the parent (**place** collection in this case)

Comment: Thanks ! I hope there was an easier way like in the MongoDB driver with "$push" to push something into an array of JSON. But your method is more "Sails way" of doing thing so thank you ;)

Comment: Glad I could help you mate, G.luck